# blocked by CORS and also fail accessing REST API endpoint with Amplify Functions

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify, apollo-server

I am following this link to deploy an Apollo GraphQL Server with Amplify Functions:
https://dev.to/aws/10-minute-tutorial-deploy-an-apollo-graphql-server-with-amplify-functions-38p1

However, when I run "npm start", it fails to access 'http://localhost:3000', showing:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://******.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/graphql' 
from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an 
opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch 
the resource with CORS disabled.
```

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED   
******.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/graphql:1
```

Here is how I set exports handler in index.js for Lambda:

```
exports.handler = server.createHandler({
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
    credentials: true,   // I tried setting false is also the same
  },
});
```

I am not sure whether CORS is the root cause because I think the above config should make it work. I suspect that something going wrong for API end point. I see the failure using browser to access REST API endpoint, which is the link in aws-exports.js:

```
awsmobile.aws_cloud_logic_custom[0] = "******.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev"
```

It shows:

```
{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}
```

And I cannot access "******.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/graphql" either, showing:

```
{"message": "Internal server error"}
```

Is it because of missing AWS signature? Anything else I need to config for authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spent a few days, and found out the root cause. It is neither CORS nor authentication issue.

According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/amazon-api-gateway-using-stage-variables.html, it is expected to see "Missing Authentication Token" because I shall access to child resource instead of the endpoint itself. The child resource here is "******.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/graphql".

> The Invoke URL link points to the root resource of the API in its beta
> stage. Navigating to the URL by choosing the link calls the beta stage
> GET method on the root resource. If methods are defined on child
> resources and not on the root resource itself, choosing the Invoke URL
> link returns a {"message":"Missing Authentication Token"} error
> response. In this case, you must append the name of a specific child
> resource to the Invoke URL link.

For why it failed to access "******.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/graphql", I found that error by checking CloudWatch logs. It is a great tool for debug.

```
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'apollo-server-lambda'",
```

"amplify push" couldn't recognize this package because I used a terminal with node v6.9.5. After I update it to latest node and "amplify push", problem is solved.

CORS error is a distract, it doesn't show up after the above issue is fixed. CORS header wouldn't be added because index.js failed to compile.

Comment: It is true: "CORS error is a distract". I also found the root error in CloudWatch logs.